# Creating list using JSON - IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Tags: android, list, instagram

Im trying to get json data from instagram api regarding a specific tag. from the response im saving all the urls to a custom class Image with just a String url attribute. In each instagram response it has about 20 media files but i cant seem to construct my list of images to display in my recycler view

response.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
                if (response.isSuccess()) {

```
                mEditText.setText("secces");
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.body().byteStream()));
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                    }

                    JSONObject tagResponse = new JSONObject(sb.toString());

                    for (int i = 0; i < tagResponse.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject pagination = tagResponse.getJSONObject("pagination");

                        mMaxId = pagination.getString("next_max_id");
                        mMinId= pagination.getString("next_min_id");

                        JSONObject meta = tagResponse.getJSONObject("meta");
                        JSONArray data = tagResponse.getJSONArray("data");

                        for (int j = 0; j < data.length(); j++) {

                            JSONArray tags = data.getJSONObject(j).getJSONArray("tags");


                            JSONObject images = data.getJSONObject(j).getJSONObject("images").getJSONObject("low_resolution");
                            mEditText.setText(images.getString("url"));

                            Picture picture = new Picture();
                            picture.setURL(images.getString("url"));

                            mAdapter.addImage(picture);

                        }
                    }
                    //displayResults(data);


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //Log.d(TAG, "CallonResponse isSuccess " + sb.toString() + " ----- ");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            //Log.d(TAG, "CallonResponse onFailure! " + t.getMessage());
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

When I do the following lines...

```
Picture picture = new Picture();
picture.setURL(images.getString("url"));
mAdapter.addImage(picture);
```

According to my debugging skills I am able to get images.getString("url") 
I feel like there is some problem in either the creation of picture but that doesnt make sense since all picture class has is one attribute so there might be a problem in addImage. Below Im posting a code for my adapter...

public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private List<Picture> mPictures;
public ImageAdapter(){
    mPictures = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View row = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sample_layout, viewGroup, false);
    return new Holder(row);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int i) {
    Picture currPic = mPictures.get(i);
    Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(currPic.getURL()).into(holder.mPhoto1);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 600;
}

public void addImage(Picture picture) {
    mPictures.add(picture);
}

public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private ImageView mPhoto1, mPhoto2;
    public Holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mPhoto1 = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
        //mPhoto2 = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image2);
    }
}
```

}

/edited:

This code is in my main activity at the very bottom and it sets up the views...it worked well for a different project so I assumed this is how I would set this up as well

```
private void configViews() {
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        //mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(VR_SPAN_COUNT, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
//        mAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
//        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 600;
}

why it is always returnin 600?

Comment: youre right, that was just me fooling around... I have changed that as per other suggestions thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you create your adapter with empty array mPictures.

You have to do the following:

In your activity/fragment you have to create list of pictures, for example:

`List<Picture> mPictures = new ArrayList<Picture>;`

and when you iterate your response (data), you have to use 
`mPictures.add(picture);` instead `mAdapter.addImage(picture);`

After the loop, you have to create your adapter `ImageAdapter mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(mPictures);` and set it to Recycler view - `mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);`.

Also you have to change your adapter constuctor like that:

```
public ImageAdapter(List<Picture> pictures){
        mPictures = pictures;
}
```

The method getItemCount() in your adapter have to looks like:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mPictures.size();
}
```

The method addImage() in the adapter is not need any more. That's all.

Comment: Wow, your approach makes so much more sense, I realise now that I wasnt creating the array at all lol. So I tried that right now and Im still getting the same error but I still feel I took a step in the right direction. At the moment Im putting mPictures into my adapter once it finishes going through the data.

Comment: Also, Im really confused about the recyclerview I think there might be a problem in that. Ill try to edit and show you how im setting it up .

Comment: when I debug it i see that the array is being filled. Its size is increasing as well as its getting populated with the images. when i access individual elements and log them I can see the urls.

Comment: Also, I just realized that even though I defined my array at the top of my file...it seems to become size 0 outside the on response method

Comment: I finally got it to work. I honestly dont know why it works but i moved some thing from the configviews to at the top of my oncreate. like instantiating my layout manager and setting it to the adapter. I know in hind sight it makes sense but can someone explain this? Also what about the other things in my viewconfig method, i mean im not using them now but what do they do??

Answer (score 0):

Since you have your hardcoded 600 items, the recyclerview wants to get the items displayed and asks for the first element(0)

```
Picture currPic = mPictures.get(i);
```

then throws the exception since you have no pictures.

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mPictures.size();
}
```

and

```
mAdapter.addImage(picture);
recyclerView.notifyItemInserted(adapter.getItemCount()-1)
```

should do the right thing